# Why does this SQL Server statement start with a semicolon (;)?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Searching the web for some help on joining/splitting/denormalizing data using XML with SQL Server, I found [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/526912/Generating-and-Splitting-a-Delimited-String-Column), and I was intrigued by the starting semicolon in the sample - pasted below. Why is that ; there ?

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        DeveoperID,
        CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(ProjectCodes, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS ProjectCodes
    FROM @DeveloperProjectCSV
)
SELECT 
    DeveoperID,
    xTable.xColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS ProjectCode
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY ProjectCodes.nodes('//r') AS xTable(xColumn)
```

Comment: Considering that there is no closing ";", where it normally is, it appears that whoever coded this prefers the reverse logic of starting the statement with a ";" to ensure the previous statement is closed.  In the end, just like a comma-delimited list, it really only matters visually, as long as there is a proper close somewhere in there.

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx): "; - Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used to end the previous statement or batch of statements in there is any, so it is really part of the previous statement.

If the `with` is the first statement it is not needed. It's often included in the `with` by habit I guess, even when it's not needed. I tend to do this too just to be sure the previous statements are ended, but the correct use of the semi-colon would be to use it at the end of the previous statement (where it belongs).

The documentation for common table expressions states that:

> When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the
>   statement before it must be followed by a semicolon.

Some useful documentation:

MSDN: [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: *I tend to do this too just to be sure ...* but it's confusing. `;` should be present @ the end of the statement.

Comment: @Rahul I agree, it's a bad habit, but pretty common in my experience.

Comment: Your answer is completely correct and I think it's even a typing error - there are more mistakes in that text like "DeveoperID" or "A SELECTquery returns" etc.

Comment: Does that imply that we cannot have nested CTEs ?

Comment: @iDevlop CTEs cannot be nested in the traditional sense, but you can have one cte referenced by another: `with cte1 as (select ... ), cte2 as (select * from cte1), cte3 as (select * from cte3)` etc.